# Is there a way to convert SearchQuerySet to the type that objects.filter returns? -Django

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I need to convert a SearchQuerySet() (django-haystack) object to the type that objects.filter return. I then need to be able to filter it.

For example if a have a SearchQuerySet() with Restaurant model objects, I need to be able to do this:

1) convert that to the type that objects.filter returns
2) Be able to filter the result of doing 1) e.g. `restaurant_locations= r.filter(location = "New York")`

I know it sounds silly, but I need this functionality. Any insight is appreciated

Comment: What is a `SearchQuerySet` and from where it is coming? `django-haystack`? Please mention that.

Comment: I am no sure what `SearchQuerySet` is, but my guess is that inherits from `Queryset`

Comment: Yes, SearchQuerySet() and it is django-haystack

Comment: So `SearchQuerySet()` supports filtering on it. Whats the issue? index your `location` field and filter on it. You can not filter on fields which are defined in your model but not are in your index.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I know, but is it possible to convert it to a Queryset? This is why I wrote "I know it sounds silly"

Answer (score 3):

A `SearchQuerySet` *is* a `QuerySet`, and operates exactly as a `QuerySet` but is based on the fields you set up in the index, not those the model.

So if your model has the field `foo` and your index doesn't, you can't do `SearchQuerySet().filter(foo='thing')`.

If you can't add fields to the index, and absolutely have to filter on the whole list of models, you can do a ***horribly expensive*** conversion like so:

```
sqs = SearchQuerySet().get_some_results
qs = Mymodel.filter(id__in=[result.obj.pk for result in sqs])
qs = qs.filter(foo="thing")
```

However, this iterates across the `SearchQuerySet` to get all the primary keys, and then passes this whole list back into the dataabse to get the items, which you can then filter on.

Comment: Ah I see. You bring up good points. Thank you for the response.